# How to display PresentModelViewController in StoryBoard

Tags: ios7, uistoryboard, presentmodalviewcontroller

Im,, developing an iphone app using story board. This is my first storyboard application. There are several `ViewControllers` embeded in a `NavigationController`. What I want to do is when I click on a button an another `ViewController` that already embedded in a navigation controller should be visible as a `PresentModelViewController`. But I cannot use `self.navigationController.PresentModelViewcontroller` since it shows as deprecated. How do I display a viewcontroller that already embeded in navigation controller in my storyboad.

please help me, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way of presenting a view controller as a model view controller,

```
//set an identifier of your view controller
NSString *identifier = @"IdentifierOfTheViewController";
//initiate your view controller
YourViewController  *yourController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
//add it as modelViewCotrller
[self presentViewController:yourController animated:YES completion:nil ];
```

As simple as that :)

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question well, [here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-game-programming/using-modal-storyboard-segues-iphone-programming/) is a simple tutorial for presenting modal in storybard.

`presentModelViewcontroller` is deprecated, and you are calling it inappropriately, you should do this:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:nil];
```